# Transform open ended science based questions to more acceptable format

Tags: discussion, opinion-based, science

I would like to explore methods to achieve psionic like effects using known, science based, phenomenon.

For instance:

Instead of an empathy psionic based power what about people that are highly trained in techniques such as reading facial expression and body language?
Instead of people who move a Monte Carlo ball around with their mind what about performing massive calculations deciphering the physics of the Monte Carlo ball?

I have a list of possible techniques, but I do not want to query each technique separately. I would like to see what contributors come up with and compare it to my list.

My concerns are:

This may be considered opinion based despite the presence of scientific evidence. 
This site tends to work on hypothesis testing.

Is there a way to change this question so it fits better for this site?

Comment: Hi Halo8tds. This is what the sandbox is for. I'd encourage you to post your question there, and highlight your concern. I'm closing this as a duplicate of the sandbox question, but if you can make a strong argument that this doesn't fit in the sandbox, please [Edit] the question to highlight that and we'll look at reopening this one.